# footer css zoom bug

Tags: html, css, zooming, footer

Hi i have problem with footer.. when i zoom page i scroll page through and don't show orally

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wez8/16

my code:

css:

```
#border {width: 1020px; margin: 0 auto;}
#bottom {min-width: 100%; bottom: 0; height: 35px; position:fixed; position: device-fixed; background-color:#FFF; box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #888888;}
#bottom ul li {display:block; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; float:right;} 
#bottom ul li a {color:#616161; font-size: 11px;}
```

html:

```
<div id="bottom">
<div id="border">
 <ul>
        <li><a href="#">aaa </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bbbbbbbb </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sssssssssss </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaas </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">cccccccccca </a></li>
    </ul>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the NSFW free image hosting link... try to reproduce your problem in a JSFiddle instead, sometimes it even helps you find the cause of it...

Comment: the link is NSFW xD, the ads are not p0rn but still... xD

Comment: this my problem... http://jsfiddle.net/2Wez8/16/ scroll not working:s and when i zoom it hide my list